# Using apache-camel multicast to upload one file to diffeerent locations

Tags: java, apache-camel

How to use multicast to upload one file twice to the same sftp location but two different folders using a single login?

Say i have **locationA** as my pick-up location, b & c are my file destination locations in the sftp.

**I have something like:**
from(locationA)
.multicast()
.to(locationb, locationc)

I guess this will need loging-in twice but i need to do that once.

Please help.

Comment: If I understand your question, you have to copy one file to two different locations?

Comment: Yes you are right. The lacations are in the SFTP sever. I can access both lacations with the same account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try  without multicast, and change the file name in the `CamelFileName` header, and call the same endpoint again. And make sure to have `disconnect=false`, as that means Camel will reuse the same connection.

```
from X
  to FTP a
  setHeader CamelFileName = new file name
  to FTP a
```